# PHPDoc inheritance of exceptions thrown by method in the function body with PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm, cqrs, phpdoc

I would like to inherit PHPDoc for exceptions thrown in a dispatcher to improve documentation and be aware of all the possible exceptions thrown.

```
class SomeController
{ 
   ...
   /**
     * @return JsonResponse
     * ### MISSING AUTO GENERATED PHPDOC: @throws SomeException 
     */
    public function changePassword()
    {
        /** @uses SomedHandler::handleSomething()*/
        $this->commandBus->dispatch(Something::fromArray([
        ...
        ]));

        return new JsonResponse(null, Response::HTTP_NO_CONTENT);
    }
}


class SomedHandler extends SimpleCommandHandler
{
    /**
     * @param Something $something
     * @throws SomeException
     */
    public function handleSomething(Something $something)
    {
        throw new SomeException();
    }
}
```

As shown in above I can't get the thrown exceptions nested in the handler. My attempt was to use tag `@uses` with the class and the method to dispatch, but PhpStorm isn't generating the exceptions for the method `handleSomething()`. While `@uses` helps the navigation I would like to get the exceptions thrown as well.

Comment: Seems like it isn't possible to use it this way.

Comment: with the tag @uses I see isn't possible but I was wondering whether could be another way to achieve it

Comment: Unfortunately, no, unless you define `@throws ...` for the `dispatch` method. You could mark it so it throws abstract `GeneralDispatchException` and make handlers define their own exceptions inherited from it.